# Can I release a CGPDFDocumentRef if I have retained one of it's CGPDFPageRefs and hope the page does not go away?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, pdf, quartz-graphics

Specifically, for the sake of encapsulation, I would like to use an accessor like:

```
- (CGPDFPageRef)pageCreate {
   // Assume url exists and is valid
   NSURL *url = [self url];
   CGPDFDocumentRef document = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)url);
   CGPDFPageRef result = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(document,1);
   CGPDFPageRetain(result);
   CGPDFDocumentRelease(document);
   return result;
}
```

I'm assuming that those using the method would know the page has been retained (thus putting the word create in the method name even if it's slightly misleading) and that they need to release it when they have finished using it.

The question is... would the page be valid since I have released the document or would I be trying to access a released thing?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are not calling it asynchronously it's ok.

By default NSRunLoop creates NSAutoreleasePool each time it loops - so every variable with 0 retainCount can be deallocated before next loop comes in - which means you can finish all your functions as long as they are not asynchronously - it will not loop in between of your code.

For async you need to create your own NSAutoreleasePool.

Comment: Sorry that's not what I asked.

Answer (score 0):

Your example code is fine, releasing the document won't cause any issue with the page.

If the page needed the document for some reason to be valid then it would retain it internally, so nothing you need to worry about.